# Mean Value Theorem continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, frechet-derivative

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $F$ is Gateux-differentiable at all points $x\in X$. For any pair of points $x,x+t\in X$ there exists $\beta\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
F(x+t) - F(x) = DF(x+\beta t)t
$$

As a demonstration I define a function
$$
\tau : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \alpha \mapsto \tau(\alpha) = F(x+\alpha t)
$$
I want to try $\tau$ which is continuous in $[0,1]$. I tried using the definition but I had problems. Could you suggest some other way?

---

Sea $X$ un espacio de Banach. $F$ es Gateux-diferenciable en todo punto $x \in X$. Para cualquier par de puntos $x, x+t \in X$ existe $\beta \in (0,1)$ tal que
$$
F(x+t) - F(x) = DF(x+\beta t)t
$$

Para la demostración definí una función
$$
\tau : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad \alpha \mapsto \tau(\alpha) = F(x+\alpha t)
$$
Quiero probar $\tau$ que es continua en $[0,1]$.
intente por definición pero tuve problemas, ¿podrían sugerirme algún otro camino?.

Comment: I think questions in English are more likely to be answered. Unfortunately I am a monoglot.

Comment: Espero que puedas ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

$\tau$ is actually not only continuous but even differentiable. Just write down the definition of the derivative of $\tau$ at $\alpha$ and of the Gateaux derivative of $F$ at $x+\alpha t$ and compare.

Comment: I can see that,$\tau' (\alpha) = DF(x+\alpha t) t$, but I want to know, how to show continuity over $[0,1]$ of $\tau$?

Comment: If you agree that $\tau$ is differentiable at every $\alpha\in[0,1]$, you have the continuity: Every differentiable function is continuous. If you do now know this fact: $\tau(\alpha+h)-\tau(\alpha)$ must tend to $0$ as $h\to0$, since otherwise the fraction $(\tau(\alpha+h)-\tau(\alpha))/h$ could not tend to a finite number.

Comment: In the left end-point $\alpha=0$ you have to take the one-sided limit $h>0$, of course, and in the right end-point $\alpha=1$ the one-sided limit $h<0$. Maybe it is confusing you that the mean-value theorem needs only the continuity at the end-points and not the one-sided derivative: You have actually more than you need...

Comment: I want to show by definition $\epsilon $, $\delta$ that $\tau $ is continue on [0,1].

Comment: GIven $\varepsilon>0$, choose $\delta_0>0$ such that $|(\tau(\alpha+h)-\tau(\alpha))/h-\tau'(\alpha)|<\varepsilon$ for all $h\ne0$ with $|h|\le\delta_0$. Choose $\delta=\min\{\delta_0,\varepsilon/(|\tau'(\alpha)|+\varepsilon|)\}$. Then, if $|h|\le\delta$, there holds $|\tau(\alpha+h)-\tau(\alpha)|\le|h|(|\tau'(\alpha)|+\varepsilon)\le\varepsilon$.